# Intercept "git commit -a(m)"

Tags: git

I like the fine-grained commits that the git index allow, i.e. the staging of individual files or even hunks through `git add` before the final commit. Unfortunately, sometimes after spending some time staging a particular commit, muscle-memory kicks in so that I `git commit -a -m "msg"`. Then I either have to live with it, or jump through some `reset` or `--amend` hoops.

Is there a way for me to (ideally, globally) configure Git so that if I issue a `git commit -a`, it gets intercepted? Maybe a script asking me to confirm if I really want to commit all? I've thought about delegating the commit operation to a wrapper script (e.g., "gitcommit"), but do not think that will work very well as it does not stop me from doing a `git commit -a -m "msg"`, which is the problem in the first place.

Comment: Is it really that hard to `git reset --soft HEAD^` after a mistaken commit?  Is it really that hard to get the index in the state you really wanted it in and issue `git commit --amend`?  I'd drop the idea of intercepting the commands of the tool you are using and just *learn how to effectively use the tool*.

Comment: @cdhowie: No, it is not hard. But I was wondering if there was a better way. If there is, then I think I have learned how to adapt the tool to my needs, *and* my tool has "learned" from me how to work better. If there is not, then I have learned about the tool's limitations and will adapt my workflow/mindset to adjust.  IMHO, flexibility/adaptability/"learning" is as desirable in tools as much as the user! Or do you see plug-ins, add-ons, wrapper/helper scripts, resource configurations, etc. for your Vim/Bash/IDE/etc. as all evidence of failing to learn how to effectively use a tool?

Comment: I think your muscle memory would adopt as soon as you add an extra prompt. How about a `pre-commit` hook? It can't detect `-a`, but it would intercept commits.

Comment: @Jeet: No, plug-ins are fine as they add significant, useful extra functionality.  But when a tool gives you a one-liner to undo something, it's really not worth adding a prompt.  Prompts are mainly useful for confirming (1) irreversible actions, and (2) uninterruptible long-running operations.  Also, as J-16 said, you will train yourself to ignore the prompt just as you trained yourself to commit.  Git makes backing up *so incredibly easy* that you are going to waste more time giving yourself a prompt than you would typing in a quick reset/amend command.

Comment: @cdhowie: "significant, useful" ... I agree! A lot of people have insert mode abbreviations to correct "teh" to "the" in Vim. I don't, because this is not useful for me, as I do not make this mistake often. On the other hand, I make the `commit -a` mistake enough that fixing it Git-wise strikes me as a useful change *for me*. And while it might be a one-liner to do the reset, many times re-staging a carefully-planned out set of commits is not. Hence the motivation for my question. I understand that you don't see the gain or significant utility of rewiring Git this way, and that's fine.

Comment: @Jeet: My point is simply that `git reset --soft` will not require re-staging anything.  It will drop the latest commit **without touching the index or working tree**, which means it will *exactly* undo the commit command.  You will not need to re-stage anything, just pick up where you left off.

Comment: @cdhowie: Thanks for clarifying this. If this is indeed the case, then you are absolutely right that Git has an out-of-the-box solution for my situation, and using this approach is better than hacking in an intercept. Which also means that you are right about me needing to learn to use it better, which I have, and I appreciate your contribution to this!

Comment: @cdhowie: I checked `git reset --soft`, and, unfortunately, it leaves the extra files added via the `-a` flag in the index. Example script is here: http://pastie.org/1335618. The ideal fix for my fat finger flub would be to have the index staging only "file1.txt" and "file2.txt". Otherwise, preventive measures (i.e., intercepting the overly-enthusiastic commit) might be a better option (for me0.

Comment: @Jeet: Ah, I see -- yes, since `-a` will alter the index if you proceed with the commit `git reset --soft` won't do much to revert that.  In this case, `git commit -a` does qualify as an "irreversible action" (to some extent; at least potentially not *easily* irreversible when staging complex commits).  So yes, now I can see why having a prompt would be a good thing in this scenario.  Sorry for my pig-headedness.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [pre-commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks):

something like this (not tested)

.git/hooks/pre-commit

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff-files --quiet    # check if the working directory have non-staged files
DIRTY_WORKING=$?

if [ ! $DIRTY_WORKING ] ; then        #  check if we are committing all files
   # list all files to be committed
   git diff-index --name-status --cached HEAD

   echo "Are you sure? (type YES to continue)"
   read VALUE
   [ "x$VALUE" != "xYES" ]
   exit $?
fi
exit 0
```

You can find out the number of files to be committed using  `git diff-index --cached HEAD | wc -l`.  But I think I would leave this to yourself.

Comment: This looks promising. Maybe if the script could check the index to see if, for example, more than one file was staged and only prompt then, it might work. Even better, if there was some way to check if the set of files about to be committed includes all modified tracked files, that would be an indirect way to infer whether "-a" was actually used? Of course, if it leaves all the files added to the index with the "-a" flag in the index, it means I have to rebuild the index even if I cancel ...

Comment: I have updated the answer. Again, this is not tested. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it will work in principle. I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make `git` an alias that runs a script you create that looks at the command line arguments and lets you know if you typed `commit` followed by `-a` on the command line.

Personally, I never use `commit -a` and instead always use `git add -u` plus `git commit`.